# ¿Cómo adjuntar un archivo para enviarlo por correo?

Tags: c#

El programa manda el correo electrónico sin problemas y adjunta el archivo, pero cuando reviso el correo al cual mandé esta información noto que no llegó el archivo adjunto no logro explicarme por que.

El ejemplo que vi decía que agregara esto en el botón enviar: `Attachments.Add(new Attachments (archivo));`

```
public partial class CorreoGmail : Form
{
    private string archivo;    // VARIABLE DE ARCHIVO 

    public CorreoGmail()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        archivo = "";  // INICIAMOS VARIABLE ARCHIVO 
    }    

    private void ButEviacorreo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        EnviarEmail gmail = new EnviarEmail();

        string usurio = "correoelectronico@gmail.com";
        string password = "contraseña12345";
        string dequien = "conocido";                       

        bool exito = gmail.EnviarMail(textBox1.Text,textBox2.Text,textBox3.Text, de, user, pass);
        if (exito == true)
        {                   
            MessageBox.Show("Correo enviado correctamente ");
            textBox1.Text = "";
            textBox2.Text = "";
            textBox3.Text = "";       

        }
        else    
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Correo no enviado");
        }
    }

    private void ButtoAdjuntar(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {              

        if (CargarArchivo.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            archivo = CargarArchivo.FileName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Edita correctamente los tags de tu pregunta, el código que pones no es C sino C++. Por otro lado es imposible ayudarte si como parece, la clase que envia el correo está encapsulado en `EnviarEmail` y no nos ofreces su código y además, donde _parece que seleccionas un `archivo`_ no vuelves a utilizar más la variable en ningún sitio... Lee por favor [mcve] para saber como elaborar una pregunta en la cual te podamos ayudar.

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo una clase que puedes utilizar, la acabo de terminar y probar y funciona correctamente. Envía el correo y el archivo adjunto llega bien.

En el caso de Gmail, para evitar que te aparezca un mensaje de seguridad que no deja enviar el correo (adjunto imagen), hay que entrar en este enlace:

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Escribes tu usuario y contraseña de gmail (la cuenta que vas a utilizar para enviar el correo) y habilitas la opción **Permitir el acceso de aplicaciones menos seguras**

Imagen del error de seguridad:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que te sirva.

Aquí la clase con un ejemplo:

```
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Utilidades
{
    public class Correo
    {
        string servidorSMTP; int puerto; bool ssl = false;
        string correoRemitente;
        string nombreRemitente;
        string correoDestinatario;
        string asunto;
        string mensaje;
        string contraseña;
        string archivoAdjunto;

        public string ServidorSMTP { set { servidorSMTP = value; } }
        public int Puerto { set { puerto = value; } }
        public bool SSL { set { ssl = value; } }
        public string CorreoRemitente { set { correoRemitente = value; } }
        public string NombreRemitente { set { nombreRemitente = value; } }
        public string CorreoDestinatario { set { correoDestinatario = value; } }
        public string Asunto { set { asunto = value; } }
        public string Mensaje { set { mensaje = value; } }
        public string Contraseña { set { contraseña = value; } }
        public string ArchivoAdjunto {set { archivoAdjunto = value; } }

        public void Enviar()
        {
            try
            {
                MailMessage correo = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

                correo.From = new MailAddress(correoRemitente, nombreRemitente, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                correo.To.Add(correoDestinatario);

                correo.Subject = asunto;
                correo.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

                correo.Body = mensaje;
                correo.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

                correo.IsBodyHtml = false;

                correo.Priority = MailPriority.High;

                correo.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(archivoAdjunto));

                smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(correoRemitente, contraseña);
                smtp.Port = puerto;
                smtp.Host = servidorSMTP;
                smtp.EnableSsl = ssl;

                smtp.Send(correo);
            }
            catch (System.IO.IOException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No se encontró el archivo " + archivoAdjunto, "Envío de Correo", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
            catch (SmtpException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Envío de Correo", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ejemplo:

```
Correo correo = new Correo();

correo.CorreoRemitente = "correo.remitente@gmail.com";
correo.CorreoDestinatario = "correo.destinatario@xxxxx.xxx";
correo.Contraseña = "***********";
correo.NombreRemitente = "Nombre remitente";
correo.Asunto = "Tu asunto";
correo.Mensaje = "Tu mensaje";
correo.ArchivoAdjunto = @"C:\Archivo.txt";
correo.ServidorSMTP = "smtp.gmail.com";
correo.Puerto = 587;
correo.SSL = true;

correo.Enviar();
```